# bash scripting input from 3 files

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

The original data from which I've created these 3 files

```
quota   username        bytes   
20480000        user1@abx.com       896
30720000        user2@abx.com     3002766
20480000        user3@abx.com        20472940
20480000        user4@abx.com      2351

Here I want that if bytes if any user is equal or greater than to quota then the username should be printed or I'll perform another task to block the user.
```

I have 3 files such as these:

`users.txt`

```
Output:
abc@abc.com
xyz@abc.com
```

`consumed_quota.txt`

```
Output:
20
5
```

`allowed_quota.txt`

```
Output:
20
10
```

I want that if user `abc@abc.com` from file `users.txt` `consumed_quota` is equal to or greater than `allowed_quota` then print the user.

What would be the bash program?

Kindly help out.

I'm trying below code, but it is printing all users in stead of the matching one.

```
#!/bin/bash



mysql -e 'select postfix.m.quota, q.* from postfix.mailbox m, postfix.quota2 q where m.username = q.username' > /tmp/all_users_query

username=`cat /tmp/all_users_query | cut -f2 | grep -v username > /tmp/usernf`
quota=`cat /tmp/all_users_query | cut -f1 | grep -v quota > /tmp/quotaf`
consumed=`cat /tmp/all_users_query | cut -f3 | grep -v bytes > /tmp/consumedf`


function show_users()
{
        username=`cat /tmp/usernf`
        for i in $username
        do
        echo $i
        done

}


function actual_quota()
{

        quota=`cat /tmp/quotaf`
        for i in $quota
        do
        akb=`echo $i/1000 | bc`
        amb=`echo $akb/1000 | bc`
        echo $amb
        done

}

function used_quota()
{

        consumed=`cat /tmp/consumedf`
        for i in $consumed
        do
        ukb=`echo "$i/1000" | bc`
        umb=`echo "$ukb/1000" | bc`
        echo "$umb" 
        done

}

declare -a arr_users="$(show_users)"
declare -a arr_act_quota="$(actual_quota)"
declare -a arr_use_quota="$(used_quota)"


for u in ${arr_users[@]}
do

for i in ${arr_use_quota[@]}
do

#       echo $i;

        for j in ${arr_act_quota[@]}
        do

        if [ "$j" == "$i" ]
        then
                echo $u;
                break;
        fi
done
        done
done
```

Comment: Is the first line in these files literally `Output:`?

Comment: What did you tried ? We can help you fixing issue on your script, but we won't write it for you from scratch.

Comment: I see you have a database. Why don't you write the query so that you get the desired output from the start?

Comment: I don't know the query that is why I'm doing it. If you know, please guide me if you know.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the lines saying `Output:` are not actually part of the data,

```
$ paste users.txt consumed_quota.txt allowed_quota.txt | awk -F '\t' '$2 >= $3 { print $1 }'
abc@abc.com
```

The `paste` command creates a tab-delimited data set where column 1 is the usernames, column 2 is the used quota, and column 3 is the allowed quota.

The `awk` program reads this tab-delimited data and prints the username if the used quota is larger than or equal to the allowed quota.

---

Alternatively, query the database directly for the usernames that have exceeded their quota:

```
mysql -e '
    SELECT q.username
    FROM postfix.quota2 q
    WHERE q.bytes > q.quota'
```

Comment: Above is not working

Comment: @User4283 In what way is it not working?

Answer (score 0):

For your request, you don't need to split the data into 3 files then have to read files.
You can directly read from `/tmp/all_users_query`

Otherwise, @Kusalananda, answer is a fairly sufficient and fully functional answer.

I have checked the files you've described, and determined they've originated from the query (fairly obvious) with the following order::

`allowed_quota`   `users`   `consumed_quota`

So I came up with the following::

```
#!/bin/bash

mysql -e 'select postfix.m.quota, q.* from postfix.mailbox m, postfix.quota2 q where m.username = q.username' > /tmp/all_users_query

gawk '{ if ($3 >= $1) { printf("\n%s ", $2); } }' /tmp/all_users_query

exit 0
```

Another (better) solution is to have an additional field in the output (that you can discard if you're reading the output file somewhere else). The additional field is called `overflow`, and it shows how many bytes in overflow the user has consumed; that is, the simple difference between `consumed_quota` and `allowed_quota`.

The output is ordered by the overflow field, in descending order so that it shows highest consumption first.

```
#!/bin/bash

mysql -e 'select postfix.m.quota, q.* from postfix.mailbox m, postfix.quota2 q where m.username = q.username' > /tmp/all_users_query


gawk '{ allowed_amount = $1; consumed_amount = $3; if (consumed_amount >= allowed_amount) { overflow = (consumed_amount - allowed_amount); printf("\n%s\t%d", $2, overflow); } }' all_users_query | sort --key=2gr


exit 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I've created the script myself and got the desired results.

```
#!/bin/bash

rm -rf /tmp/over_quota_users

mysql -e 'select postfix.m.quota, q.* from postfix.mailbox m, postfix.quota2 q where m.username = q.username and q.bytes >= m.quota-bytes;' | cut -f2 | grep -v username > /tmp/over_quota_users

#Function to get users;

function show_users()
{
        username=`cat /tmp/over_quota_users`
        for i in $username
        do
        echo $i
        done

}


#Function to get active users;

function check_active()
{
        for i in $(show_users); do
        mysql -e 'select username, active from postfix.mailbox where username = "'$i'" and active = 1;' | grep -v username
        done
        result=`echo $?`
        echo $result


}

active_results=$(check_active $(show_users))

if [ "$active_results" == 1 ];
then

        exit 0;
else
        for j in $(show_users); do

    #changing over quota users to inactive.

        mysql -e 'update postfix.mailbox set active = '0' where username = "'$j'"';

        done

        rm -rf /tmp/oqa_ul_2_admin.txt

        echo "" > /tmp/oqa_ul_2_admin.txt
        echo "These users were over quota and active "  >> /tmp/oqa_ul_2_admin.txt
        echo "" >> /tmp/oqa_ul_2_admin.txt
        echo "---------------------------------------" >> /tmp/oqa_ul_2_admin.txt
        echo "$(show_users)" >> /tmp/oqa_ul_2_admin.txt
        echo "" >> /tmp/oqa_ul_2_admin.txt
        echo "---------------------------------------" >> /tmp/oqa_ul_2_admin.txt
        echo "" >> /tmp/oqa_ul_2_admin.txt

        /usr/bin/mail -s "Blocked Over quota and active users" emailto@me.com < /tmp/oqa_ul_2_admin.txt



fi
```